# Three js - Have object move towards camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an object that I want to move directly towards the camera when given the proper input.

I've taken a look at `Object3d.translateOnAxis(axis, distance)`, but I can't seem to set the `axis` (the object's local axis) to always face the camera. This may be because the object is also rotating.

Since I have multiple objects on the scene, I need the objects to move towards the camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to get it working. Say I want `object` to travel towards the point (0, 0, 25) in world coordinates. `object.translateOnAxis(object.worldToLocal(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,25)),50);` will make the object travel 50 units towards the point (0, 0, 25) from its current location.

Answer (score 0):

For me what's working to move the object 5 meters is:

```
var dir = new THREE.Vector3();
dir.subVectors(camera.position, object.getWorldPosition(dir)).normalize();
object.translateOnAxis(dir, 5);
```